# Rupes Recta, The Straight Wall, Correct Translation

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check, new-latin, latin-to-english-translation, science

*Rupes recta* is the name given to a feature on the Moon. This feature is also known as the straight wall or straight cliff.

Is *rupes recta* the correct Latin phrase for straight wall or straight cliff?

The phrase may have originated during the 1600s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, depending on the type of wall.

[*Rūpēs, -is*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Drupes) is a third-declension feminine noun derived from *rumpō* "break, split". It means a rock which is split apart or has a smooth face; I've seen it translated as "cliff", "canyon", or just plain "rock" (e.g. *rūpēs Tarpeia* is "the Tarpeian Rock").

[*Rectus, -a, -um*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Drego) started as the past participle of *regō* "to keep straight". Eventually *rectus* became more popular than *regō*, so it's often analyzed as an independent adjective meaning "straight, perpendicular, horizontal; correct, accurate, proper". Compare English "rectify", "correct", "rectangle".

From the looks of it, the *Rūpēs Recta* on the moon is definitely a smooth rock face, and is definitely (kind of) straight, so the name seems appropriate.

Comment: Astronomers say Rupes Recta is a fault, possibly 5 faults, rising about 300 meters, running over 100 kilometers. It is not a sharp cliff, but a shallow slope. However, the name is now official.

Comment: I mean, early astronomers couldn't see the steepness...so the ambiguity isn't their *fault*. (Ba-dum *tsss*)

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't resist.